# Perl XML:LibXML setAttribute not changing the document

Tags: xml, perl, xml-attribute, xml-libxml

I'm trying to change an XML attribute using Perl.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<Node>
  <NodeX attr1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>
</Node>
```

the Perl script contains:

```
my @nodes = $doc->findnodes("//Node/Nodex");;
if (@nodes) {
  my $res = $nodes[0]->hasAttribute("attr3");
  if ($res) {
    foreach (@nodes) {
      $_->setAttribute('attr3', "10");
    }
  }
}
```

As result the script does not change the attribute. I have already tested the permissions and the script can write and read the XML file using `print`.

`setAttribute` seems to do nothing at all despite `hasAttribute` returning true.

Comment: How do you check that the attribute hasn't been changed? Where do you output the XML? Can other aspects of the document be changed?

Comment: I simply read the XML file once the script has completed. The rest of the document is processed in XSLT and all the remaining attributes are set according to the functions specified in XSLT. Other questions?

Comment: Are you perhaps parsing a file into a DOM, making changes to the DOM, but forgetting to write the changed DOM back to the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the node is `NodeX`, not `Nodex`. That is all that is wrong with your code (except that, from your comments, it seems you may not be writing the altered XML back to the file) but this shows a more concise method that you may prefer.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'__END_XML__');
<Node>
  <NodeX attr1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>
</Node>
__END_XML__

my ($attr) = $doc->findnodes('/Node/NodeX/@attr3');

$attr->setValue(10) if $attr;

print $doc->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Node>
  <NodeX attr1="1" attr2="2" attr3="10"/>
</Node>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue was exactly the second that you mentioned, not writing back changes. I (wrongly) assumed that setAttribute() would have done it for me.